# Getting Too many Email Invocations: 11 for the test class

Tags: apex, failing-tests

Getting Too many Email Invocations: 11 error..
have no idea to resolve that error

Any help is much appreciated.

This class is used to send email notification to groups when a case created/updated

**apex class**

````
 
public 
with sharing class CaseEmailService{

  
    public 
    static void sendEmailonInsert(List<Case> newCaseList){ 
        Map<Id,Product_and_Owner_Settings__mdt> prodMap = new Map<Id,Product_and_Owner_Settings__mdt>();

        String prdQueueID;
        List<Product_and_Owner_Settings__mdt> listEmailDomain =
            [SELECT Id, 
                    MasterLabel, 
                    ProductId__c, 
                    Queue_ID__c 
              FROM Product_and_Owner_Settings__mdt
                    WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED];
            
        for(Product_and_Owner_Settings__mdt mdtList: listEmailDomain){
             prodMap.put(mdtList.Queue_ID__c,mdtList);
         }
        //To fetch the Org Default Address
        OrgWideEmailAddress[] owea = [SELECT Id from OrgWideEmailAddress WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED LIMIT 1];
        
        //TO fetch the Email Template Name
        EmailTemplate emailTemplate = [SELECT Id,Subject,Description,HtmlValue,DeveloperName,Body from EmailTemplate WHERE DeveloperName ='Case_Creation_Email_Template' WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED];
        //List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> allmails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
        for(Case c : newCaseList){
             System.debug('1.Number of Queries used in this apex code so far: ' + Limits.getQueries());
             System.debug('2.Number of rows queried in this apex code so far: ' + Limits.getDmlRows());
              if(string.valueof(c.OwnerId).startsWith('00G') && prodMap.containsKey(c.OwnerId)){
                  prdQueueID = c.OwnerId;
              }
            if(prdQueueID !=null && c.ownerid == prdQueueID){
                List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> allmails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
                Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
                    mail.setSaveAsActivity(false);
                    mail.setToAddresses(getReciepientEmails(prdQueueID));
                    
                    mail.setOrgWideEmailAddressId(owea[0].id);
                    
                    
                    String Casedescription;
                    if(c.Description !=null){
                         Casedescription = c.Description;
                    }else{
                         Casedescription='';
                    }
                    mail.setSubject('[Awesomizer Case Notification] Case assigned to '+c.Case_Owner_Name__c+ 'queue needs attention');  
                    String body = 'The following Case was just added to '+c.Case_Owner_Name__c+' queue and needs attention <br/><br/>';
                    body += 'Case #:'+c.CaseNumber+ '<br/>';
                    body += 'Subject :'+c.Subject+ '<br/>';
                    body += 'Description :'+Casedescription+'<br/><br/>';
                    body += 'Click on the link to access the case:'+System.URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm()+'/'+c.Id+'<br/>';
                    mail.setHtmlBody(body);

                   allmails.add(mail);
                Messaging.SendEmailResult[] results = Messaging.sendEmail(allmails);
                if(results[0].success){
                    system.debug('****Email sent***');
                }else{
                    system.debug('****Email not sent***');
                }
            }
            
                
        }
         
        
    }
    
    
    public 
    static void sendEmailonUpdate(List<Case> newCaseList, Map<Id, Case> oldMap){ 
        Map<id,Product_and_Owner_Settings__mdt> prodMap = new Map<Id,Product_and_Owner_Settings__mdt>();
        Map<Id,Product_and_Owner_Settings__mdt> prodMap1 = new Map<Id,Product_and_Owner_Settings__mdt>();

        String prdQueueID;
          List<Product_and_Owner_Settings__mdt> listEmailDomain =
            [SELECT Id, 
                    MasterLabel, 
                    ProductId__c, 
                    Queue_ID__c 
              FROM Product_and_Owner_Settings__mdt
                    WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED];
        
        //To fetch the product and QueueID configuration 
        for(Product_and_Owner_Settings__mdt mdtList: listEmailDomain){
                prodMap.put(mdtList.Queue_ID__c,mdtList);
        }
        //To fetch the Org Defulat Address
         OrgWideEmailAddress[] owea = [SELECT Id from OrgWideEmailAddress WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED LIMIT 1];
        //To Fetch the Custom Email Template  
        //EmailTemplate emailTemplate = [SELECT Id,Subject,Description,HtmlValue,DeveloperName,Body FROM EmailTemplate WHERE DeveloperName ='Notify_Queue_Members_for_Case_Updation' WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED];

        for(Case c : newCaseList){
            if(c.ownerId != oldMap.get(c.Id).ownerId && string.valueof(c.OwnerId).startsWith('00G'))              
                if(prodMap.containsKey(c.OwnerId)){    
                     prdQueueID = c.OwnerId;
                }
                
           
       
             if(prdQueueID !=null && c.ownerid == prdQueueID){
                List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> allmails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
                Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
                    mail.setSaveAsActivity(false);
                    mail.setToAddresses(getReciepientEmails(prdQueueID));
                    
                    mail.setOrgWideEmailAddressId(owea[0].id);
                   
                    String Casedescription;
                    if(c.Description !=null){
                         Casedescription = c.Description;
                    }else{
                         Casedescription='';
                    }
                    mail.setSubject('[Awesomizer Case Notification] Case assigned to '+c.Case_Owner_Name__c+ 'queue needs attention');  
                    String body = 'The following Case in '+c.Case_Owner_Name__c+' queue received a new update and needs attention <br/><br/>';
                    body += 'Case #:'+c.CaseNumber+ '<br/>';
                    body += 'Subject :'+c.Subject+ '<br/>';
                    body += 'Description :'+Casedescription+'<br/><br/>';
                    body += 'Click on the link to access the case:'+System.URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm()+'/'+c.Id+'<br/>';
                    mail.setHtmlBody(body);
                 allmails.add(mail);
                Messaging.SendEmailResult[] results = Messaging.sendEmail(allmails);
                if(results[0].success){
                    system.debug('****Email sent***');
                 }else{
                    system.debug('****Email not sent***');
                } 
            }
        }
    }
    public
        static List<String> getReciepientEmails(Id prdQueueID){
           List<String> ReciepentEmais = new List<String>();
            Set<Id>userIds = getGroupEmails(prdQueueID);
            system.debug('1111userIds'+userIds);
           for(User u: [SELECT Id,Email,isActive FROM User WHERE Id In:userIds and isActive=true WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED]){
            if(u.Email !=null){ 
             ReciepentEmais.add(u.email);
           }
         } 
          return ReciepentEmais;
        }
    
    
   public 
      static Set<Id> getGroupEmails(Id queueId){
    
        Set<Id>userIds = new Set<Id>();
        Set<Id>groupIds = new Set<Id>();
        groupIds.add(queueId);
        do {
            Set<Id> tempGroupIds = new Set<Id>();
            for(GroupMember objGM : [ SELECT UserOrGroupId FROM GroupMember WHERE GroupId IN:groupIds WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED] ) {
                String strUserOrGroupId = objGM.UserOrGroupId;
                if (strUserOrGroupId.startsWith('005')){
                    userIds.add(objGM.UserOrGroupId );
                 }
                else{
                    tempGroupIds.add(objGM.UserOrGroupId);
                }
            }
             system.debug('userIds111'+userIds);
             system.debug('tempGroupIds'+tempGroupIds);

            groupIds = tempGroupIds;
            
        } while (groupIds.size() > 0);{
            return userIds;
        }
    
    }
    
}```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are facing to the System.LimitException. This usually happens when you do smth in a loop. In your case you are sending emails for each Case cycle. You need to put all emails together and send at once after the for cycle.

Initialize a collection before for

```
 Messaging.Email[] messages = new Messaging.Email[0];
```

Instead of

```
 Messaging.SendEmailResult[] results = Messaging.sendEmail(allmails);
```

You need to add a message to a list

```
  messages.add(mail);
```

And after for clause add

```
 Messaging.sendEmail(messages);
```